# rails pagy multiple tables on one page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7, pagy

I have two different tables on one page and I want to use pagy on each of them.

For sorting/searching I changed names of each pagy object so I did it like

```
 @pagy_inv, @invoices = pagy @invoices.reorder(sort_column_show_city_invoices => sort_direction_show_city_invoices), items: params.fetch(:count, 10)
```

and

```
 @pagy_ord, @orders = pagy @orders.reorder(sort_column_show_city_orders => sort_direction_show_city_orders), items: params.fetch(:count, 10)
```

which works fine for sorting and searching, but when I try to change page, it sends page parameter and tries to change page for every table and therefore if one table has like 5 pages and another 10 and I try to move to page 10 it fails because one of the table cannot move to not existing table.

I was thinking to change page param (for example page_inv and page_ord) but how to do that? Or is there some easy way how to change page only for table from selected pagy object?

Answer (score 1):

As you already understood, pagy use a default `:page_param` (which is `:page`): if you use more than one instance in the same page you should differentiate the `:page_param` of different instances or they will use all the same.

You can pass that in the `pagy` method (as you did with `:items`).